# form_for remote not working in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

I am running into a stranger error in Internet Explorer.

I have a form_for with remote => true.

In turn, when the create action is called there is an associated create.js.erb file.

When I hit submit it IE the browser askes me to download the returned create.js.erb file.

This only occurs when I tried to upload an image in the form.

I do not understand what the problem is.

The form works in Firefox and Chrome.

I am using remotipart for the image upload (not sure if that helps).

In addition, I am using paperclip for the image attachments.

Below I will post my view, controller, and create.js.erb.

View:

```
 <% form_for @post, :remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
                        <%= f.text_area :message, :value => "What's up?" %>
                        <div id="newPostBottom">
                            <div id="newPostBottomRight">
                                <div id="loading">
                                    Sharing <%= image_tag('spinner.gif') %>
                                </div>
                                <%= f.submit "Share", :class => 'button' %>
                            </div>
                            <div id="newPostBottomLeft">
                                <%= f.label :channel, "Select Channel:" %><%= f.select :channel, channels, :prompt => "Choose..." %>
                                <div id="postImageUpload">
                                    <%= image_tag('icons/camera.png', :id => 'postUploadImageIcon', :alt => 'Upload Image', :title => 'Upload Image') %>
                                </div>
                                <%= f.file_field :post_image %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
 def create
account = Account.getAccountById(session[:user])
@post = account.posts.build(params[:post])

payload = {
    "account_id" => account.id,
    "name" => account.name,
    "message" => params[:post][:message],
    "channel" => params[:post][:channel]
}
if @post.save
    Pusher['front-post-feed-channel'].trigger('front-post-feed-create', payload)
else
    render :nothing => true
end

 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
 reset_session
 end
```

Create.js.erb:

```
 $("#post_message").val("What's up?");
 $("#post_message").css({height: '30px'});
 $("#newPostBottom").hide();
 $("#postsHomeFeed").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/posts/new_post', :locals => {:post => @post})) %>");
 $("#loading").hide();
 $("#post_submit").show();
 $("#post_channel").val('');
 $("#post_post_image").val('');
 if($(".noContent").length > 0) {
$(".noContent").remove();
 }
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the contents of your `create.js.erb` file in a `remotipart_response` block:

```
<%= remotipart_response do %>
  $("#post_message").val("What's up?");
  $("#post_message").css({height: '30px'});
  $("#newPostBottom").hide();
  $("#postsHomeFeed").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/posts/new_post', :locals => {:post => @post})) %>");
  $("#loading").hide();
  $("#post_submit").show();
  $("#post_channel").val('');
  $("#post_post_image").val('');
  if($(".noContent").length > 0) {
    $(".noContent").remove();
  }
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a file limit size in IE?  I did what you said and I can get smaller size images to work now, but larger ones do not.

Comment: got it to work. had to add what you suggested plus some javascript code

Comment: Which version of the Gem are you using? I think the most recent 1.0 version gets rid of the need for the surrounding block, but older versions still required it.